Modals verbs in the past specific instances
"When my car broke down I thought she could help us."
To me that sentence is wrong. We don't use "could" with specific instances in the past. Thus, we have to have change "could" to "was able to" or choose a different modal for example "might" which is used with specififc situations. Do I understand this grammar point  correctly?

"I thought she would be able to help us" is a much more natural and likely thing to say, but your version might be valid in some circumstances. (For instance 'I believed at the time that she had the mechanical knowledge to enable her to help'.)

But could there is wrong, right?

I said explicitly that it was not entirely wrong (it might be valid in some circumstances, such as in my example), but that "would be able to" is much more idiomatic.

The most likely reason for mentioning the "possibility / ability" of her helping is because actually she didn't. In which case you'd be more likely to say "When my car broke down I thought she could have helped us" (or ...I thought she would have helped; in almost all cases they're both equivalent, to me).

I don't see any need to convert could to were able to. The following sentences all sound idiomatic to me:

I thought we could walk home when the car broke down, but the children were too cranky and tired, so I phoned for a taxi.
I knew we could walk home when the car broke down since the children were game for any adventure.
I thought we could walk home when the car broke down, and the children, who were game for any adventure, proved me right.

might works there for all three sentences but sounds a tad marginal  nowadays for the second, because of "knew", but it would still work for some older speakers. would works  for the first two but is odd for the third.

I was told that we don't use "could" with specific situations like " Yesterday, when my car broke down I could fix it". Is this fine or I need to replace "could" with something there?

.what do you think?

My examples are also past specific instances, and they are idiomatic, and therefore the "past specific instance" is not the only factor involved: to fix something, you need ability, and in the case of automobiles that means know-how and the proper tools and sometimes the needed replacement parts; to say that you did indeed have the ability to fix a car on a particular past instance, you would say I was able to fix it.    So the relevant meaning is the deciding factor when choosing between could {verb} and was able to {verb}

could can express what was perceived to be a viable choice or option on a past occasion.  The viability of the choice shades into ability.   "When I got home and discovered that I had left my keys in my locker at school, I thought I could get in through the basement door, because we often forget to lock it. But no such luck. That door was locked too."
